# For .. in Handlebars & Express-flash

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I tried to use the package "express-flash" for NodeJS with Handlebars, all is good but I can not loop over "messages.errors". This is the code of my view "flash.hbs':

```
{{#if messages.errors}}
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="alert">
        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
    </button>

    {{#forEach messages.errors}} {{ errors }} {{/forEach}}

</div>
{{/if}}
```

The div it's empty when i got an error, but he has the class "danger".He detect the errors, but no retrieve it.
I feel that it is not possible to loop with handlebars ...

Thank you :)

Comment: I forget the most important, "messages.errors" comes from "express-validator"

Answer (score 0):

It's all good. 
It was {{#if messages.errors}} {{#each messages.errors }}     {{ **this.msg** }}  {{/each}} {{/if}}